# Resize a byte array image in pixels

Tags: java

I have an image stored as a byte array. Regardless how large the size, I want to always resize it down to 100x100 pixels.

I am trying to convert the byte array into a bufferedimage, resize and save it back as a bytearray. But with the following code, the images no longer appear on my page.

```
byte[] pict; // this array contains the image
BufferedImage bufferedImage;

ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(pict);
try {
    bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(bais);
    bufferedImage = Scalr.resize(bufferedImage, 100);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write( bufferedImage, "jpg", baos );
    baos.flush();

    pict = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
o.write(pict);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way instead:

```
Image tmpImage = ImageIO.read(bais);
Image scaled = tmpImage.getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

Then, to convert to a byte array, convert the image into a bufferedimage and then that into the byte array:

```
BufferedImage buffered = ((ToolkitImage) scaled).getBufferedImage();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(buffered, "jpg", baos);
baos.flush();
pict = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
```

Comment: If I do this, how do I change it back to a byte array.

Comment: What are you trying to get it to appear in?

Comment: Images are coming from a database. The above codes along with database connection codes that fill up the byte[] pict is in a jsp file. I am sending this data over to another jsp page to display the image. When I o.write(pict);  without writing any of these codes to re-size, the data is sent over fine and the images appears.